# Swift Codable - How to make types with references to each other codable?

Tags: json, swift, encoding

I got two classes like this:

```
class Session {
  var name: String
  var data: [Double]
  var routes: [Route]

  init(named name: String, data: [Double] = [], routes: [Route] = []) {
    self.name = name
    self.data = data
    self.routes = routes
  }
}
```

```
class Route {
  var session: Session
  var startIndex: Int
  var endIndex: Int

  // A route stores only references to the real underlying data stored in a Session
  var data: [Double] { Array(session.data[startIndex...endIndex]) }

  init(session: Session, startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) {
    self.session = session
    self.startIndex = startIndex
    self.endIndex = endIndex
  }
}
```

Note that a Route object cannot be initialised without a corresponding Session, it always depends on it. The goal is to store in Route only references to the real data stored in the Session object.

**First, is there a potential retain cycle in this pattern, and how to break it if there is one?**

**Second question:** I want to make a Session Codable. The problem is as Session relies on Route and Route on Session I can't make one Codable without making the other too and I fall into an endless loop.

I don't necessarily require that Route conforms to codable as a route will always depends on a Session, an exemple JSON would be:

```
{
  "name": "Session Name"
  "data": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  "routes": [
    {
      "start_index": 3
      "end_index": 8
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

From this I would be able to recover a Session from a JSON.

---

I tried:

- Using a `nestedContainer` but it requires Route to be Codable.
- Conforms Route to Codable ignoring session but I can't since the decoder required an intitializer to init all properties. I could use a default `session` and then changing it back to the real session but it feels awkward and not very robust.
- Defining a decoder `init` with an additional argument session, but I can't access this initializer after. Maybe I can extend and overload the decode method of JSONDecoder to take this into account?
- Session is Identifiable, maybe the best solution is to decouple Session and Route by assigning a session_id to Route.

Comment: Remove the session property from  Route, if you ever need to directly access Session from Route then use a protocol solution like a delegate

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you mean creating something like a SessionDelegate that would provide functionality of Session to Route ?

Comment: Yes kind of. It depends on why/how Route needs to access Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've modeled **is** a circular dependency and can't be represented in JSON. The easiest solution is to change the `session` property on route.

```
weak var session: Session?
```

This prevents a retain cycle and makes it so that session isn't required in `Route.init`. With that change in place you can then loop through all the `Route`s at the end of your `Session` initializer and assign the session.

The downside to this solution is that you need to write your own initializers, but it sounds like you were experimenting with that anyway.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution, even though it’s not very handy to unwrap the optional each time. I also thought about explicit optionals as normally a Route can’t exist without a Session.

Comment: @LouisLac glad to hear that works for you. If you're happy with the answer would you mind accepting it as correct?

Comment: Sure, I was just taking my time to wait for other answers but yours is correct

Comment: out of curiosity: is there an existing encoder that supports circular dependencies out of the box that we can use to encode e.g. NSManagedObjects with inverse relationships? Since my Core data entity graph is quite complex your solution would require a lot of manual work